# PHP - Remove text that is bold

Tags: php, regex, text

I have some text for ex: `This is <b>an</b> example <b>text</b>.`

How would I remove all the text that is within bold tags, so it should output this:

`This is example.`

Comment: More proper, semantic markup uses <strong> not <b>....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php)**
If you would like to remove a simple tag along with the text inside it:

```
<?php 
$string = 'This is <b>an</b> example <b>text</b>';
echo preg_replace('/(<b>.+?)+(<\/b>)/i', '', $string);
```

**Output:**
This is example

---

And whit a regular expression (class, id), spacing errors and antislashe:

```
<?php
$string = 'This is <b class="c1" id=\'c2\'>an</b> example <b>text</B >'; 
echo preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1.*?>@si', '', $string);
```

**Output:**
This is example

Comment: This only removes the bold tags, I want it to remove the text inside the bold tags as well.

Comment: Hmm, funny thing. I posted a regex before you, someone downvoted because it's apparently "sinful" to use regexes with html, but you got accepted :P. Good for you.

Comment: @Soule, your regex does not work the right way, it removes all phrase in the first and last tag! it is not asking that...

Comment: Okay, It works in ruby, I didn't have PHP set up at the time. If your works, then thats good :) I removed the answer.

Comment: @Soule, it has nothing to do with the fact that you used it in ruby. Your regex removed *everything* from the first `<b>` to the last `</b>`, so aside from the fact that the answer used regex, even the regex was wrong. It's not "sinful" to use regex for this, it's just very bad practice. This is similar to C's undefined behavior. By choosing this "easy" but totally wrong way, the OP will find eventually that everything works for him, everything works in testing, nothing is apparently wrong, but then the app blows up in his most important customer's face.

Comment: @Radu Okay, but what do you think about this regex? (atmon3r). Doesn't it do the same thing?

Comment: @Soule, it doesn't do the same thing (it's non-greedy and it should work correctly with the exact situation provided by the OP, as opposed to the greedy version you provided), but it is a regex. Duly downvoted.

Comment: I'm not from your point of view, as stated Radu, code Soule retired from the first tag to the last, my code removes each tag and its contents. I see no evil to do this

Comment: @atmon3r, that's just what I said in the previous comment. However, since you're not using an HTML parser, but rather a regex, there are a *lot* of edge cases in which your solution will fail. For example (just the first thing I thought about), consider the following perfectly valid HTML: `<b class="c1">a</B >`.

Comment: @Radu exact... I simply responded to the request but it is possible to do otherwise, what's you recommended for this? use DOM?

Comment: @atmon3r, it's not only possible, but it's the *only* correct way to handle this. Yes, using an HTML parser like `DOMDocument::loadHTML()`.

Comment: @Radu I see exactly what you mean,i did not think about that but i'm sure he can improve the code with **preg_replace()**. i will do some tests tonight

Comment: @Radu fixed for a regular expression (class, id), spacing errors and antislashe, answer edited

Comment: @atmon3r, this removes all tags, not just `<b>`s. Also, what happens if you have `< /b>`, or `< b>`, or `<(newline)b>`?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
echo str_replace(array('<b>', '</b>'), '', 'This is <b>an</b> example <b>text</b>');
```

There may be better techniques. Here I just replace every occurence of the sequences in the array with an empty character. For more info, see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). They have a similiar example there:

```
// Provides: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

**Edit.** I missed the regex tag, but regex is a teeny bit overkill for this purpose?

Comment: Yeah, regex is overkill. Didn't think about str_replace though ;)

Comment: No worries. If I'd read the tag I would probably had gone the same way as you did. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that is not what I want. You see with the above code it only removes the bold tags, however, I want it to completely remove the text inside the bold tags.

For ex:

`Hi <b>Hello</b>`

Output should be:

`Hi`

Comment: Oh, I must be blind. @Soule: it's your time to shine?